# Linked List using Void* pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, void-pointers

I want to create a generic linked list in C/C++ (without using templates of C++).
I have written following simple program and it works fine as of now -

```
typedef struct node
{
    void *data;
    node *next;
}node;


int main()
{
   node *head = new node();

   int *intdata = new int();
   double *doubledata = new double();

   char *str = "a";
   *doubledata = 44.55;
   *intdata = 10;

   head->data = intdata;

   node *node2 = new node();
   node2->data = doubledata; 
   head->next = node2;

   node *node3 = new node();
   node3->data = str;
   node3->next = NULL;
   node2->next = node3;

   node *temp = head;
   if(temp != NULL)
   {
    cout<<*(int *)(temp->data)<<"\t";
    temp = temp->next;
   }
   if(temp != NULL)
   {
    cout<<*(double *)(temp->data)<<"\t";
    temp = temp->next;
   }
   if(temp != NULL)
   {
    cout<<*(char *)(temp->data)<<"\t";
    temp = temp->next;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

My question is - 
I need to know the data type of the data I am printing in the code above. 
For example - first node is int so i wrote -
*(int *)(temp->data)
second is double and so on...
Instead, is there any generic way of simply displaying the data without worrying about the data type?

I know you can achieve this with templates, but what if I have to do this in C only ?

Thanks,
Kedar

Comment: Ahh, C/C++, that magical language free of scary templates and full of employment opportunities...

Comment: The whole point of a `void *` in C is that you *don't* know the type. Without knowing the type, you cannot sensibly "display the data". You don't even know *how much* data there is to display.

Comment: Why not use `boost::any` ?

Comment: It can't be C; there's no `new` operator in C.

Comment: Agree with Kerrek SB. This kind of code generates a lot of employment.  Mostly in bugfixing.

Answer (score 5):

The whole point of a generic list is that you can store anything in it.  But you have to be realistic...  You still need to know *what* you are putting in it.  So if you are going to put mixed types in the list, then you should look at using a Variant pattern.  That is, a type that provides multiple types.  Here's a simple variant:

```
typedef struct Variant
{
    enum VariantType
    {
        t_string,
        t_int,
        t_double
    } type;

    union VariantData
    {
        char*    strVal;
        int      intVal;
        double   doubleVal;
    } data;

} Variant;
```

You can then tell yourself "I'm storing pointers to Variants in my `void*` list.  This is how you would do it in C.  I assume when you say "C/C++" you mean that you're trying to write C code but are using a C++ compiler.  Don't forget that C and C++ are two different languages that have some overlap.  Try not to put them together in one word as if they're one language.

Answer (score 0):

In C, the only way to achieve generics is using a `void*`, as you are already doing. Unfortunately, this means that there is no easy way to retrieve the type of an element of your linked list. You simply need to know them.

Comment: Actually, there's also the possibility of using macros to implement a "node" that has a specific type.

Comment: But then you have to create a new macro for every different type that you want to put into your linked list.

Comment: @MatsPetersson But that is the same as typing a cast for every specific pointer type, it just looks better.

Comment: No, I mean you can make a linked list declaration, that takes a type as an argument, and generically stores a list of that type - once the list is declared, all list items contain what you are expecting (e.g `int` or `double` or `string`). But of course, you can't store a bunch of different things in the same list - but that's a pretty useless feature most of the time ANYWAYS, since you actually need to know what it was you stored, and then cast to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

The way of interpreting data in memory is completely different for different data type.
Say a 32 bit memory block has some data. It will show different values when you typecast it as int or float as both are stored with different protocols. When saving some data in memory pointed by variable of type void*, it does not know how to interpret the data in its memory block. So you need to typecast it to specify the type in which you want to read the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit like sticking all the cutlery in a drawer, but instead of putting knifes in one slot, forks in another slot, and spoons in a third slot, and teaspoons in the little slot in the middle, we just stick them all in wherever they happen to land when chucking them in, and then wondering why when you just stick your hand in and pick something up, you can't know what you are going to get.

The WHOLE POINT of C++ is that it allows you to declare templates and classes that "do things with arbitrary content". Since the above code uses `new`, it won't compile as C. So there's no point in making it hold an non-descriptive pointer (or even storing the data as a pointer in the first place).

```
template<typename T> struct node
{
    T data;
    node<T> *next;
    node() : next(0) {};
};
```

Unfortunately, it still gets messier if you want to store a set of data that is different types within the same list. If you want to do that, you will need something in the node itself that indicates what it is you have stored.

I have done that in lists a few times since I started working (and probably a couple of times before I got a job) with computers in 1985. Many more times, I've done some sort of "I'll store arbitrary data" in a something like a `std::map`, where a name is connected to some "content". Every time I've used this sort of feature, it's because I'm writing something similar to a programming language (e.g. a configuration script, Basic interpreter, LisP interpreter, etc), using it to store "variables" that can have different types (`int`, `double`, `string`) or similar. I have seen similar things in other places, such as OpenGL has some places where the data returned is different types depending on what you ask for, and the internal storage has to "know" what the type is.

But 99% of all linked lists, binary trees, hash-tables, etc, that I have worked on contain one thing and one thing only. Storing "arbitrary" things in a single list is usually not that useful.

Answer (score 0):

The answer below is targeting at C++ and not C.  C++ allows for what you want, just not in the way that you want to do it.  The way I would implement your problem would be using the built-in functionality of the virtual keyword.

Here's a stand-alone code sample that prints out different values no matter the actual derived type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class Base
{
public:

    virtual void Print() = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:

    virtual void Print()
    {
        std::cout << 1 << std::endl; // Integer
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:

    virtual void Print()
    {
        std::cout << 2.345 << std::endl; // Double
    }
};

class Derived3 : public Base
{
public:

    virtual void Print()
    {
        std::cout << "String" << std::endl; // String
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    // Make a "generic list" by storing pointers to a base interface
    std::list<Base*> GenericList;
    GenericList.push_back(new Derived1());
    GenericList.push_back(new Derived2());
    GenericList.push_back(new Derived3());
    std::list<Base*>::iterator Iter = GenericList.begin();
    while(Iter != GenericList.end())
    {
        (*Iter)->Print();
        ++Iter;
    }

    // Don't forget to delete the pointers allocated with new above.  Omitted in example

    return 0;
}
```

Also notice that this way you don't need to implement your own linked list.  The standard list works just fine here.  However, if you still want to use your own list, instead of storing a `void *data;`, store a `Base *data;`.  Of course, this could be templated, but then you'd just end up with the standard again.

Read up on [polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) to learn more.